# What is the next number in the sequence? 1, 3, 8, 120,?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$1,3,8,120$?

When multiplied together the product equals one less than a perfect square.
Example: $3*8=24 \Rightarrow 24+1=25 \Rightarrow$ A perfect square

Comment: You should point out that multiplying together any two distinct members gives one less than a perfect square.  It is also a set, not a sequence, in that the order of the elements does not matter.

Comment: Why not 5 $(3*5+1=16)$ is the 3rd one?

Comment: 443.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 5):

There is none.  The set is given as a sequence in [OEIS A030063](http://oeis.org/A030063) where it states that it has been proven that no positive integer can be added to the list, but a rational number can.  It is conjectured that there is no five member set that has this property, but there are other four member sets and an explicit construction is given.

Comment: Huh, apparently I didn't understand the question correctly.  XD

Comment: What was with $0$?

Comment: You missed the "positive".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $1$.  See that $120\times1$ is one less than $11^2$.

Another answer is $0$.  See that $120\times0$ is one less than $1^2$.

Comment: $1$ is already in the list.  OP is looking for a new number that can be multiplied by any number in the list to give one less than a square.

Comment: @RossMillikan Apparently so.  But that was never specified in the problem.

Comment: Yes, I commented on that to OP.

Comment: @RossMillikan so... $0$ doesn't count, right?

Comment: @RossMillikan It's not obvious from the description at [A030063](http://oeis.org/A030063) that it must be a set. $1$ doesn't work if added simply because $1 \cdot 1 + 1 = 2$ is not a perfect square